# Loading coordination model in Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

What's the best way to load a coordination model in Forge:

- use Aggregatedview to load multiple Revit files
- load the navisworks model converter in Svf
- leverage the model coordination / modelset of ACC

It looks like loading an invidual NWD model is faster than loading individual Revit files. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Aggregated Revit files, if you want granular metadata.

Naviswork, if mainly for viewing purposes, here metadata is not as rich as in individual Revit files.

Model coordination is for collaboration and versioning.

Whichever suits your business needs, choose the appropriate method.